# Breaking APK into multiple parts

Tags: c#, android, mobile, unity-game-engine

How do I break an APK into multiple parts so that a framework is downloaded during installation and then the rest is downloaded according to what the user clicks on? I'm making a game in Unity which uses C#.

Comment: I haven't worked with it but [Support for Split Application Binary (.OBB)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html) seems to be standard way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use Asset Bundles:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html